# Save cell with numbers to text file

Tags: matlab, cell, txt

I have cell arrays A and B with different lengths and numbers.

```
A={1:0.5:5;1:0.5:2};
B={1:0.5:6;1:0.5:9};
C= [A;B];
```

I want to combine these cell arrays into a cell array C, which would then look like this:

```
C =

  4×1 cell array

    {1×9  double}
    {1×3  double}
    {1×11 double}
    {1×17 double}
```

Then, I want to save this into a text file, that should look like this:

```
1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000
1.0000    1.5000    2.0000
1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000
1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000   6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000    8.5000    9.0000
```

So far, I have only found code for text or same size arrays. This is my attempt, which doesn't work:

```
fid = open('filename.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%f',C{:})
close(fid)
```

Comment: `open` and `close` are not the valid commands here, you want `fopen` and `fclose`, as shown by Matteo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem might be in the format you're specifying for the `fprintf`, as I believe using only `'%f'` will print one number on each row.

One way to do this would then be:

```
    fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'wt');
    for i = 1:length(C)
        fmt = repmat('%f ',size(C{i})); % this only adds one whitespace in between numbers
        fmt = [fmt,'\n']; % remember to add a new line
        fprintf(fid,fmt,C{i});
    end
    fclose(fid);
```